# Disable iPhone vibrate with Setting Bundle [iPhone SDK]

Tags: iphone, sdk

i build an app, now i want disable my shaking with setting bundle when iphone is shaking and vibrating

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

Setting Bundle :

Title: Vibrate ////
Key : dis_vib////
Type : PSToggleSwitchSpecifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you call the vibration code, check to see what the NSUserDefaults say.

For example:

```
if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShouldVibrate"]){
   //Vibrate code
}
```

Where "ShouldVibrate" is what the settings bundle is setting.

Comment: sorry doesn't work <<<< if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"ShouldVibrate"]){ AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (kSystemSoundID_Vibrate); }>>>>

Comment: "ShouldVibrate" can be anything. Make sure it matches the key in the settings bundle you've made.

Comment: Change "ShouldVibrate" to "dis_vib".